# Is there a way to create multiple decorators with the same naming convention in Python?

Tags: python, python-decorators

We have a few decorators to register functions and classes inside imported files, that look like the following:

```
def register_crawler(func):
    register(func, "crawler")
    return func

def register_model(func):
    register(func, "model")
    return func

def register_generator(func):
    register(func, "generator")
    return func
```

In each case, we are calling another helper function that will actually perform the registraion, i.e. storing a reference to the imported object.

We have several of these decorators, registering different components. Is there a way to define a single decorators with a naming convention, plus a list of all components, so we can do something like:

```
components = ["crawler", "model", "generator", ...]
for variable in components:
    def register_[variable](func)
        register(func, variable)
        return func
```

One obvious solution is to instead define a decorator that takes the component type, e.g. `crawler`, `model`, etc as an argument, have a validator to check if the provided name matches supported components, then call the helper function. But we would lose the explicit `@register_crawler` decorator, and we would prefer to keep `@register_crawler`; `@register_model`, etc.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Any time you think about hacking things to generate names like this, it's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do... you say you want to keep the specific decorator names, but then also... define those decorators dynamically?

Comment: What do you imagine the decoration syntax would look like?

Comment: Yes, that's it -- just wondering if there is a safe way to do it. If not, we will go with explicitly defining it as we are already doing. But I figured for anything slightly exotic and hare-brained, this is probably the best place to ask :)

Comment: Well, I was hoping the syntax could remain the same, i.e. inside some script, we could keep using @register_crawler, just have the decorator itself defined dynamically, if possible.

Comment: @TimRoberts Well, this answers the question :| . Thanks though :). Will close this and reduces everyone's headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use-case for a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to me:

```
from functools import partial


def register_for(func, *, component):
    register(func, component)
    return func


register_crawler = partial(register_for, component="crawler")
register_model = partial(register_for, component="model")
register_generator = partial(register_for, component="generator")
```

`partial` has the effect of "pinning" some of the arguments to the wrapped function, which simplifies it's parameterization. Hence, you may now use your functions as simple decorators, as you hoped:

```
@register_crawler
def crawl_something(*a, **kw):
    ...
```

without rewriting the same logic over and over again.